# How to Create a Setup File for a C++ program?

Tags: c++, file, installation

How can I create a Setup File or an Installation File for a program created in Visual C++ Express

Answer (score 5):

Use [InnoSetup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php). It is quite powerful, and very well documented. And its free, of course.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean a configuration file that your program will read when it starts, the the answer is trivial: Just make a file that is (very important!) printable text: don't even think about trying to make a binary config file, perhaps because you think it's more "systemish:" that's a huge mistake that you'd regret later.

You have infinite choices wrt the layout of this file. It could be xml, but it's just as well to design your layout in a way that makes sense to you.

If you are asking something entirely different and I've missed the point of your question, then I apologize.